# c++ destructing manual

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to create code that runs fast i can.
For doing that ,I skiped some variables initializes when needed.
For example: (I can't change the labels\goto parts ,I must use it for this situation)

```
bool Func(bool BooleanParameter) {
    if (BooleanParameter)
        goto _true;
    else
        goto _false;
_true:
    string str; //Some code after that one that does with this variable
    return false;
_false:
    return true; //Exception because str doesn't initialized
}
```

But there is exception because there a way to not initialize variables and that variables destruct at the end.

Comment: Don't use goto. This has absolutely no advance.

Comment: What does “talented with perf” mean?

Comment: What do you meen by 'talented with perf'? Sounds a bit like preemptive optimization...

Comment: quiet a while I haven't seen `goto`s...

Comment: Yes, it's illegal to skip the initialization of objects with non-trivial constructors. What do you mean by "talented with perf"?

Comment: Probably TalentEd Perform: http://www.netchemia.com/TalentEd-Perform/index_sidebarDemo.asp

Comment: Stop kidding me :(. I meant fast\optimized code.

Comment: @SuperFile How were we supposed to guess that? Anyway, you seem to have huge misconceptions about what constitutes fast code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am creating scripting language ,the parser outputs object that contains label address and object ,and I need to create that dynamic and fast with labels.

Comment: @SuperFile So your parser outputs C++ code? That doesn’t sound like a good idea to begin with.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I searched for some ideas in the internet ,but didn't found one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just:

```
bool Func(bool booleanParameter)
{
    if (booleanParameter)
    {
        string str;
        // ...
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

?

This seems to achieve the desired result without dubious use of `goto` etc.

Comment: I need the label parts in the code. (Edited second ago)

Comment: @SuperFile No, *you do **not***. Paul’s code is just as efficient. And it’s valid, while yours isn’t. (But I would reverse the conditionals to reduce the indentation level of the code.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I need this because I creating macros that uses labels to make my code easy. The code I published it's just an example of what those macros does.

Comment: Why do you think you even need to use macros in C++ ? Usually this is  interpreted as a "code smell".

Comment: @SuperFile Well, your code makes no sense. I seriously doubt that your real code makes any more sense.

Comment: Gotos and labels do not make code "dynamic and fast" - they just make it unstructured. There is nothing that can be done with labels than can not be done as efficiently with structured code.

Comment: @PaulR I am creating scripting language ,the parser outputs object that contains label address and object ,and I need to create that simple and fast (I choose label for run the parser's output faster)

Comment: @PaulR My parser output labels that has `ret` (Assembly) ,and then in runtime I call all the labals. There is no faster way to do that. (You can change my mind)

Comment: Looking at some of your previous questions you seem to have a lot of misconceptions about both programming and performance. You might want to spend some time reading up on good programming techniques in general and on C++ specifically before investing a lot of time writing code based on misconceptions.

Comment: @SuperFile Trust us, a lot of us answering here have written plenty of fast code. Assembly, like any language, will get you nowhere unless you learn to read and understand it. And reading the assembly produced by the compiler, in order to make an educated attempt to improve upon it, is the very last step of optimization.

Comment: @PaulR But `goto` it's just one assembly line. BTW I asked something on combining functions with changes ,But no answer.

Comment: @SuperFile Once again, you seem to have a lot of misconceptions about assembly. Please forget about that and pay attention to structuring your code well.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Ok ,I'll wait for answer ,but now i'll construct the variables at the top of the function.

Comment: @SuperFile, `goto` is just one assembly line that causes the CPU pipeline to be flushed, resulting in a performance worse than possibly tens of linear operations.

Answer (score 1):

Try scoping the string like this

```
_true:
  {
  string str;
  return false;
  }
```

Comment: I think you forgot 'talented with perf'.

Comment: I need the label parts in the code. (Edited second ago)

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* you need the gotos, Super File?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Maybe. I think that part depends mainly on the compiler and the goto trick is useless, if not harmful. However, this shows how to make this kind of (bad) code work.

Comment: @gspr I am creating scripting language ,the parser outputs object that contains label address and object ,and I need to create that dynamic and fast with labels.